# Why my number format become scientific?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a list of numbers then I want to put comma on each number works fine, but the problem if number exceed to 14 my output become scientific format

Like this `1,.,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,E,+,2,8`

but i want to be like this `1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,`

here's sample code below

```
<?php 
$val = 11111111110000000000000000111;

$val = (string)$val; // convert into a string
$arr = str_split($val, "1"); // break string in 3 character sets

$val_new = implode(",", $arr);  // implode array with comma

echo $val_new;


?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the number is too large, so php automatically converts it into the scientific format. you can avoid this by defining the number as string initially (by putting it inside quotations)...try changing your code to this:

```
$val = "11111111110000000000000000111";
```

and remove this line:

```
$val = (string)$val; // convert into a string
```

let me know how it went.

Answer (score 2):

This is because it exceeds the [max value of an integer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php). There is nothing much you can do about it. 
Input that exceeds this limit will always be converted to a floating point representation. This means the input should immediatly be formatted as a string:

```
$val = "11111111110000000000000000111";

$arr = str_split($val, 1); // break string in 3 character sets
$val_new = implode(",", $arr);  // implode array with comma

echo $val_new;
```